# Telerik RadControl is in text format as oppose to its GUI

Tags: telerik, radscheduler

Telerik RadScheduler is showing in text as oppose to the GUI.  When I run it from Visual Studio 2010, the grid is showing just fine.  When I publish it from VS2010 to WEB server, I open my web app but the control is in text.  What am I doing wrong?

IIS 6.0 to 7.5 32-bit to 64-bit respectively
.Net Framework 3.5 to 4.0

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Code would be useful, also any differences in the web.config files might be good.